# 12.04 server installation

Tags: 12.04, server

I have a really strange problem. 
I want to install ubuntu server 12.04 from a usb flash drive. after the boot, on the installation menu screen, there is only one option: 'rescue a broken system'.
Also, the system on which I want to make the installation has no OS pre-installed.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a graphical issue and you can't see the other options.
Have you tried to press enter without pressing anything other bevor?
 Have you tried the installation on another PC with the same flash drive (it should be enough to see the menu at the beginning)?
Try the installation from a CD on the PC where you have the problem.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer, but it seems that my USB flash drive was the problem. I've made another bootable flash drive and it worked